# how to save JFrame variables when the Frame is closed and another frame opened

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jform

I am trying to save a created profile on my J-Frame. My goal is to ask the user to enter details into a Text Field (such as name, age, gender) and then save their inputs when I close my frame and open the next frame (similar to a save and continue button). I then want to be able to go back to the profile Frame (in case editing is needed) and still have the text in the Text Field. How do I do this?

Comment: Hello, no worries I solved it by placing the data into text fields

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you solved the problem, please consider writing an answer and showing the code you used to solve this. By this you might help other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a text file that is outside the src file, made a FileWriter which writes the text I needed to save to the text file. I then used a BufferedReader to access the data I needed and stored it in a variable for later use.

```
//Create FileWriter to write text to the text file
FileWritrer charName = new FileWriter("CharacterName.txt");
charName.write("Text needing to be saved goes in here");
charName.close();

//Creates BufferedReader to get data from txt file and save the line read in a variable
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("write.txt"));
String lineRead= br.readLine();//storing read line in variable for later use
System.out.println("The text in the first line goes here:\n"+ lineRead);
br.close();
```

This is the simple version, so hopefully it makes sense. If not feel free to correct me. Thanks and I hope it helps.